# How do I adjust the y-axis scale when drawing with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

The code provides the data and the functions required for ggplot drawing, but the drawn bar chart y-axis is not equidistant, which makes me confused. Please scholars answer.

```
col1 <- c('SO','MO','EO','YO','RO')
col2 <- c('J','J','J','J','J',
          'F','F','F','F','F',
          'M','M','M','M','M',
          'G','G','G','G','G')
col3 <- c('0.92966','0.94522','0.93311','0.995222',
          '0.966463','0.975725','0.976464','0.9635321',
          '0.980223','0.9124456','0.991678','0.973444',
          '0.910789','0.922','0.993444','0.956555',
          '0.923132','0.987222','0.900556','0.932228')
data <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=col1, y=col3,fill=col2)) + 
  labs(x = "col1", y = "col3")+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_discrete(
    breaks = c("J","F","M",'G'))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text( size=12, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size =12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('SO','MO','EO','YO','RO'))
```

How to draw a bar chart with y-axis range of 0.9-1 and equal spacing?

Comment: your col3 is strings, not numbers (they are in quotes).  Try `data <- data.frame(col1,col2, col3 = as.double(col3))`

Comment: Also, using a y-axis range not starting at 0 risks making the bar chart misleading - is there a particular reason you need that range?

Comment: If the Y-axis range is positioned 0-1, the picture is too ugly, and the gap between the groups is not obvious. So you want to adjust the range to 0.9-1.

Comment: Generally, if you're manipulating your data to make the gaps look bigger then you may be masking the reality of the data - I would be careful doing it.  If you insist on it, you can modify the dataset by removing 0.9 from each value, then plot and change the axis labels (not the actual scale) to show what you need (i.e if the scale is 0-0.1 you can relabel it 0.9-1.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the range by using a `coord_cartesian` with `ylim` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=col1, y=as.numeric(col3), fill=col2)) + 
  labs(x = "col1", y = "col3")+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_discrete(
    breaks = c("J","F","M",'G'))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text( size=12, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size =12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,face="bold"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('SO','MO','EO','YO','RO')) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.9, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for helping me achieve my goal. Can you explain the principle of the two codes added after the ggplot function?

Comment: Hi @TUSTLGC, great to hear it achieved your goal! The `coord_cartesian` part fixes your y-axis range and the `scale_y_continuous` part changes the offset of the graph, you can skip that if you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to redefine `col3` as numeric variable

```
data$col3 <- as.numeric(data$col3)
```

[image]

If you want to use other marks in y-axis you can use

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

getting this representation:

[image]